# How much is "motivation" a factor in a scientist's work?

Tags: motivation

How much is "motivation" a factor in a scientist's work?

I find that "motivation" is sometimes underlooked due to the perception of "being unmotivated" being a personal choice or laziness, rather than some valid mental illness or something.

OTOH, "motivation" is discussed broadly in e.g. work psychology literature. And therefore it would seem as if it does play a, possibly significant, role.

But is there any evidence that supports, just how significant is "motivation"?

Answer (score 0):

There are different aspects that will correlate with the effort you put into your work (and your satisfaction). And depending on your profession and job, they will play absolutely different roles. I can imagine

1. money (food, housing, luxury,...)
2. recognition
3. might, power
4. curiosity, interest
5. Will to change (the world), but this probably an aspect of 3
6. External pressure

I did not add "motivation" to this list, because I think those are the factors responsible for motivation. Motivation does not stand for itself. Out of own experience, in science the points 1 and 3 are typically less important and 2 and 4 far more. I would personally order those in these priorities: 4, 2, 5, 1, 3, 6

That is not representative, but from my experience and my wider environment this captures very well a typical situation.

Comment: I envy that you rank external pressure so low. I assume you have achieved tenure already?

Comment: @Roland, this is just a function of the fact that motivation is different at different times of your career for some factors. Fear of failure quickly fades if you get tenure, but may return for some.

Comment: @Roland, yes you are right. Fear is part of external pressure and is definitely "at work" in several people I am aware of in science. And you are also right: I am tenured... and I am in general a too optimistic person. All of this is a very subjective, it may be interesting to do some real statistics!

Comment: @Roland: the importance of external pressure (or more precisely: how vulnerable one is against external pressure) depends on further factors: e.g. not aiming for tenure can lower pressure quite a bit (I for one love doing research for reasons of curiosity and the kick I get out of solving problems, and therefore don't want tenure). Also money and external pressure seem to have an important interaction to me. Recognition as well, in particular for subordinate positions.  However, for several tenured professors I've met my guess would be that power is very important (one even told me directly).

Answer (score 0):

Motivation changes over time. The [answer of Ralf Ulrich](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/175379/75368) gives many of the possible motivations, but they aren't fixed over time for individuals. Idealism is an early motivator for many. Compulsion to learn and understand is important for many (most?) mathematicians and that seems to last. Fear of failure is a strong motivator, especially in today's crappy job market, but it fades as soon as tenure is achieved (if only).

But curiosity seems to be a lingering motivation for most, and recognition for some, though I never cared a lot about that. The circle in which I was known was pretty small, but I was having fun doing what I was doing. The satisfaction of growing insight was enough.

Sharing with students is another strong motivator for many, though it is a bit orthogonal to "science".

But for many (Einstein, Hawking, ...) the main compulsion is jut to try to understand how the world works. Nothing more was needed. They would have been more than happy to do what they did without money or recognition or anything but internal satisfaction. I suspect the same was true for Newton and Darwin.

So, in some sense, motivation, what ever it is, is fundamental. Amazon workers aren't particularly "motivated" by their employment. But scientists also need to deal with frustration and fairly long periods of not obviously making progress (Hawking, again).